# PrintWriter not allowing me to enter a specific directory

Tags: java, io, printwriter

```
try{
    pw = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\SDSAD\\Desktop\\java\\file.txt");
}catch(Exception exc){
    System.out.println();
}
```

Just been playing around with IO lately and I was trying to use PrintWriter and it worked at first, like for example when I just put:

```
pw = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
```

It worked completely fine, am I not allowed to set a specific directory in PrintWriter or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

PrintWriter should be used only on files, see the javadocs:

> ```
> * @param  fileName
> *         The name of the file to use as the destination of this writer.
> *         If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size;
> *         otherwise, a new file will be created.  The output will be
> *         written to the file and is buffered.
> ```

What do you expect it to do when run on directory?

EDIT: After the question changed.

You are doing everything fine, I would expect that you don't have that file in given directory or you don't have read permissions to access it.

Comment: Typo on my end, originally at the end I had the file.txt. My bad.